# salt on my user password

Tags: php

Heey Guys

It is such that I only like to do this to my side not only is sha1. but is a little safer to log in and many other things.

Now try I make an example.

```
function generateSalt($length) {
      $alphabet = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';
      $alphabet_length = strlen($alphabet);
      $salt = '';
      for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
          $salt .= $alphabet[rand(0, $alphabet_length - 1)];
      }
      return $salt;
  }

  /*
  * Opret bruger på siden og kan har mulighed for alle ting!..
  */

 function bruger_opret_siden(){
         if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT NULL FROM `bruger` WHERE `brugernavn` = ?'))
         {
             $stmt->bind_param('s', $brugernavn);
             $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
             $stmt->execute();
             $stmt->store_result();
             $count = $stmt->num_rows;
             $stmt->close();
             if($count > 0)
             {
                 $user_found = 1;
             }
         }
         if(!isset($user_found))
         {
             if($_POST["pass"] != $_POST["gentag"])
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive ens password på siden..</li>";
             }
             if(empty($_POST["pass"]) && empty($_POST["gentag"]))
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive et password på siden..</li>";
             }
             if(empty($_POST["navn"]))
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive et Fornavn</li>";
             }
             if(empty($_POST["efternavn"]))
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive et Efternavn</li>";
             }
             if(empty($_POST["land_by"]))
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive en by</li>";
             }
             if(empty($_POST["hojde"]))
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive en Højde</li>";
             }
             if(empty($_POST["email"]))
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive en Email</li>";
             }
             if(empty($_POST["brugernavn"]))
             {
                 $errors = 1;
                 echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Angive en Højde</li>";
             }

             if(!isset($errors))
             {
                 $pb = null;

                 include 'function/class.upload.php';
                 $handle = new Upload($_FILES["file"]);

                 if($handle->uploaded)
                 {
                     //lidt mere store billeder
                     $handle->image_resize = true;
                     $handle->image_ratio_y = true;
                     $handle->image_x = 220;
                     $handle->Process("profil-img/store");

                     //til profil billede lign..
                     $handle->image_resize = true;
                     $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                     $handle->image_y = 115;
                     $handle->image_x = 100;
                     $handle->Process("profil-img");

                     //til profil billede lign..
                     $handle->image_resize = true;
                     $handle->image_ratio_crop = true;
                     $handle->image_y = 75;
                     $handle->image_x = 75;
                     $handle->Process("profil-img/lille");
                     $pb = $handle->file_dst_name;            

                 }

              $password = $_POST["pass"];
              $algorithm = '$6$'; //<--- Dette betyder SHA 512
              $salt = $this->generateSalt(16); //<--- SHA 512 bruger et 16 tegn langt salt

              $hash = crypt($password, $algorithm . $salt);

             if ($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('INSERT INTO `bruger` 
             (`rank`, `email`, `brugernavn`, `password`, `profilbillede`, `profilbillede_godkendt`, `navn`, `efternavn`, `alder_d`, `alder_m`, `alder_aar`, `status`, `kon`, `seksualitet`, `land_by`, `hojde`) 
             VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'))
             {

                 $stmt->bind_param('issssisssssiiisi', $rank, $email, $brugernavn, $password, $profilbillede, $pb_godkendt, $navn, $efternavn, $alder_d, $alder_m, $alder_aar, $kon, $seksualitet, $partnerstatus, $land_by, $hojde);
                 $rank = '1';
                 $pb_godkendt = '1';
                 $email = $_POST["email"];
                 $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];//C
                 $password = $hash;//C
                 $profilbillede = $pb;//C
                 $navn = $_POST["navn"];
                 $efternavn = $_POST["efternavn"];
                 $alder_d = $_POST["alder_d"];
                 $alder_m = $_POST["alder_m"];
                 $alder_aar = $_POST["alder_aar"];
                 $kon = $_POST["kon"];
                 $seksualitet = $_POST["seksualitet"];
                 $partnerstatus = $_POST["partnerstatus"];
                 $land_by = $_POST["land_by"];
                 $hojde = $_POST["hojde"];

                 $stmt->execute();
                 $stmt->close();

                 echo "godkendt";

                 }
                 else
                 {
                     /* Der er opstået en fejl */
                     echo 'Der opstod en fejl i erklæringen til ligge i databasen: ' . $mysqli->error;
                 }
             }
         }
         else
         {
             echo "<li id=\"check_not\">Dette brugernavn er optaget!!</li>";
         }
 }
```

Here's how it looks on the register page:

```
 if(isset($_POST["godkendt_bruger"]))
             {
                 $pass = $mebe->generateSalt();
                 $users = $mebe->bruger_opret_siden();
             }
'<?php
     /*
      * Giver admin adgang til se indhold på siden.
      */
     if(isset($_SESSION["rank"]) && $_SESSION["rank"] > 0) {
         $bruger = $mebe->brugerindhold_side();
     }


     /*
      * Hvis ingen af dem så få de bare adgang sådan her..
      */
     else{
     ?>
 <form name="login" method="post" action="#">
     <h1>Log ind</h1>
     <p>Brugernavn</p><input type="text" name="brugernavn"/>
     <p>Password</p><input type="password" name="pass"/>
     <br />
     <input type="submit" name="Log_ind" value="Log ind" id="login">
     <?php
     if(isset($_POST["Log_ind"]))
     {
     $pass = $mebe->generateSalt(12);
     $login = $mebe->godkendt_bruger_login();
     }
     ?>
     <ul>
         <li><a href="">Forgot password and username</a></li>
         <li><a href="/opret-bruger/">Users</a></li>
     </ul>
 </form>
 <?php
     }
 ?>
```

This says it in when I need to log into the page:

Notice: Undefined variable: hash in /home/jesperbo/public_html/mebe/function/function.php on line 216

```
function godkendt_bruger_login(){
          $password = $_POST["pass"];
          $algorithm = '$6$'; //<--- Dette betyder SHA 512
          $salt = $this->generateSalt(16); //<--- SHA 512 bruger et 16 tegn langt salt
         if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `id`, `brugernavn`, `rank`, `profilbillede`, `profilbillede_godkendt` FROM `bruger` WHERE `brugernavn` = ? AND `password` = ?'))
         {
         $stmt->bind_param('ss', $brugernavn, $password);
         $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
         $password = $hash;
         $stmt->execute();
         $stmt->store_result();
         $stmt->bind_result($id, $brugernavn, $rank, $profilbillede, $profilbillede_godkendt);
         $stmt->fetch();
         $count = $stmt->num_rows;
         $stmt->close();

         if($count > 0)
         {
             $_SESSION["logged_in"] = true;
             $_SESSION["id"] = $id;
             $_SESSION["profilbillede"] = $profilbillede;
             $_SESSION["brugernavn"] = $brugernavn;
             $_SESSION["rank"] = $rank;
             $_SESSION["profilbillede_godkendt"] = $profilbillede_godkendt;

             if($_SESSION["logged_in"] == true)
             {
                 echo "godkendt";
             }
             else
             {
                 echo "<p>Desværre prøve igen brugernavn eller adgangskode passe ikke med vores</p>";
             }
         }
         else
         {
             echo "<p>Skrive brugernavn og Password</p>";
         }
     }
     }
```

That is to say here;

```
$password = $hash;
```

Create part works fine as it makes a long password. but that the problem is that when I log into the page.

**Hope you can help me**

Comment: 1. I don't get the real question here 2. It is usually suggested that you always code in english (this means both code and comments) no matter what your primary language is 3. Welcome to Stack Overflow.

Comment: Okay, I'll try it right the next time I promise 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
function godkendt_bruger_login(){
          $password = $_POST["pass"];
          $algorithm = '$6$'; //<--- Dette betyder SHA 512
          $salt = $this->generateSalt(16); //<--- SHA 512 bruger et 16 tegn langt salt
         if($stmt = $this->mysqli->prepare('SELECT `id`, `brugernavn`, `rank`, `profilbillede`, `profilbillede_godkendt` FROM `bruger` WHERE `brugernavn` = ? AND `password` = ?'))
         {
         $stmt->bind_param('ss', $brugernavn, $password);
         $brugernavn = $_POST["brugernavn"];
         /* ---> */ $password = $hash;
         $stmt->execute();
```

you are trying to initialize `$password` to `$hash` while there's no `$hash` defined in the scope of the function.

As your error correctly say:

> Notice: Undefined variable: hash in
>   /home/jesperbo/public_html/mebe/function/function.php on line 216

It is just making you notice that `$hash` doesn't exists and it will be converted, inside the `=`-expression to `NULL` and so is `$password`; which is obviously a behavior you do not want.

Comment: Okay, I'll try fix it for the next time I promise 100% it just seems odd since I like downloading function before the code as I show in box number 1 box where I have a function which I call "function generere salt ($ length) ". then there is a second or wrong right here. or should I copied it from the function and look like more than the login part or what?

Comment: @JesperPetersen, could you please use Google translator?

Comment: $jeffrey There are some words that I can not find out as I use google translate

Comment: @Jeffrey I tried to help Jesper in another topic. Let me explain. How he writes here pretty much resembles the output of g.translate. The problem seems to be that Danish has a different language structure. I'm Dutch and it closely matches my language in terms of basic rules. The point being, I don't think he can really accomplish any better without actually learning English. But I second your opinion, the international language for programming should be English. Automated translating from Danish to Dutch does make a lot more sense than to English.

Comment: @Digitalis, Oh ok. Yeah learning english will help him to better understand error messages too. Once he'll learn english, any error will be easy to fix.